# Windows 7 hangs after longer inactivity of user

Tags: windows-7, power-management, screensaver, freeze, standby

I have serveral PCs running Windows 7 in different falvors (32- / 64-bit / Professional / Ultimate / ATI / Nvidia) - they all have one problem in common...

...if I don't work on any of them for a longer time and the screen goes off as it should be (all default settings!) they sometimes go into some kind of sleep mode where I get to see the desktop or whatever I did before leaving after moving the mouse or pressing a key - but nothing reacts for a different amount of time from serveral seconds to serveral minutes!

Any hint that helps solving this anoying problem would be very welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your power management settings are causing problems.

In the "Search programs and files" field in the Start menu, type in:

```
change power
```

... then select the "Change power-saving settings" item.

If your options are "Balanced" or "Power Saver", select "Balanced", then click on "change plan settings".  Set turn off and sleep valus to "Never", then click "Save changes".

If that doesn't fix your problem, then you I suggest you have a look at the power management settings in your BIOS.

Matthew

Comment: Glad to help, let me know how it goes.  Are all these PCs the same hardware?